# How to render a json data into restapi?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I got a JSON response from some url. I have to show that into rest api but i got error. Here is my code

views

```
class StoreView(APIView):
    serializer_class = PostcodeLookupSerializer
    resp = requests.get('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/BN14 9GB')
    resp_data = resp.json()['result']
    result_dic = {
        'longitude': resp_data['longitude'],
        'latitude': resp_data['latitude']
    }
    result_data = JsonResponse(result_dic)

    def result(self):
        json_data = self.resp_data()
        file_serializer = PostcodeLookupSerializer(json_data, many=True)
        return Response(data=file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializer

```
class PostcodeLookupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    postcode = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
```

and url

```
urlpatterns = [
path('views/', StoreView.as_view(), name='postcode_lookup'),]
```

how to display a json response into restapi?
I got this error

```
"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return data inside response as below

return Response(data=file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)